# Kendo UI - Tying a DataSource to two kendo widgets with declarative binding

Tags: jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI and their MVVM system for my site, and I have a situation where I have a `ListView` widget that accompanies a `Pager` widget. Both of them share a `kendo.data.dataSource`. The code that wires them up looks kind of like this;

## HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="search" data-ns="auras" placeholder="Search" />
</div>
<div class="form-area">
    <div id="listView" data-ns="auras"></div>
    <div id="pager" data-ns="auras" class="k-pager-wrap"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div data-template="display-searchable-selected" data-bind="source: Auras"></div>
</div>
<br style="clear: both;"/>
```

## Kendo Templates

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="display-searchable-one">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="alert-message alert-message-default">
            <h2>
                ${ data.Name }
            </h2>
            <p>
                ${ data.Description }
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="display-searchable-selected">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="alert-message alert-message-success">
            <span class="alert-close" data-bind="click: onRemove">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </span>
            <h2>
                ${ data.Name }
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

## Javascript

```
// define the datasource for searching for auras
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '/data/auras',
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false
        }
    },
    schema: {
        total: "total",
        data: "data"
    },
    page: 0,
    pageSize: 5,
    take: 5,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax"
});

$("#pager[data-ns='auras']").kendoPager({
    dataSource: dataSource
});

var list = $("#listView[data-ns='auras']").kendoListView({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    template: kendo.template($("#display-searchable-one").html()),
    selectable: "single",
    change: e => {
        var data = dataSource.view(),
            selected = $.map(e.sender.select(), item => data[$(item).index()].toJSON())[0];
        this.Push(selected);
    }
}).data("kendoListView");

var update = (text) => {
    list.dataSource.filter({ field: "Name", operator: "eq", value: text });
};

$("[name='search'][data-ns='auras']").on('change', function () {
    update($(this).val());
});
```

Now this works okay, but there are other things like this all over my site. I am a little tired of repeating all of this javascript, so I baked the behavior into re-usable widgets. That did solve some of it, but I think I can go even further and make things easier. I want to try and do some of this declaratively with the MVVM system. So I figured I would try it out .. this is about as far as I got.

```
<div id="listView"
     data-ns="auras"
     data-role="listview"
     data-selectable="single"
     data-template="display-searchable-one"
     data-source="{ url: '/data/auras', ... }"></div>
<div id="pager" data-ns="auras" class="k-pager-wrap"></div>
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to properly wire this up, how to get that data source to work right, and how to appropriately share it with the pager - and how to tie it into the search field. Any suggestions? I would love to try and get more of this into simple declarative bindings and less into explicit javascript.

Comment: Have you looked through some of the MVVM examples on the Kendo website? Pretty much all of their widgets have MVVM samples. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/mvvm.html

Comment: Hey, thanks. I have thoroughly looked at them. I am actually pretty adept at the kendo MVVM system. It is the specific logic having to do with the DataSource that is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one of the following ways:

1. Use MVVM. Add the data source to your view model and then use `data-bind="source: ds"` for both listview and pager:

   ```
   <div id="listview" data-role="listview" data-bind="source: ds"></div>
   <div id="pager" data-role="pager" data-bind="source: ds"></div>
   ```
2. Use a global data source and the use the `data-source` attribute.

   ```
   <script>
   var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource();
   </script>
   <div id="listview" data-role="listview" data-source="ds"></div>
   <div id="pager" data-role="pager" data-source="ds"></div>
   ```

The difference is subtle. The first approach relies on MVVM which operates via the `data-bind` attribute whereas the second approach is equivalent to setting the `dataSource` configuration option. If you are already using MVVM via `kendo.bind` you could use the first approach. If you are not using MVVM you can use the second.